# in Windows XP explorer, what is the shortcuts for "redo"

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I moved the pictures from my sdcard to a folder `new photo` in my desktop.

However, I accidentally pressed `ctrl+z`.  After that, all the pictures in `new photo` were deleted.

How can I find them back? Is there any shortcuts for `redo`? I tried `ctrl+shift+z` and `ctrl+y` and `alt+shift+backspace`, but no luck.

Comment: use file recovery tools ..

Comment: This is a computer usage question, not a programming one, so it doesn't belong on [SO].

Answer (score 2):

According to this [link](http://www.helpbytes.co.uk/winshort.php) you should use ctrl + Y but [site](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061128192018AAS6ZHu) says there is no choice for "redo" in windows explorer.

here is another [site](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ph/windows7/keyboard-shortcuts) for related topic from microsoft itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the menu (top of the screen) you should be able to see something like that there.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually Ctrl+Y. But in which window are you using the shortcut?